# How to use IF Statements in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am very new to Lightning, I have checked OR,AND condition in Lightning Components.But I dont know how to write below If statements in Lightning Components.

Vfpage to Lightning.

```
<apex:column style="{!IF(!c.con.IsSnS__c && c.con.offering_group__c!='Fusion 6 Support/Subscription' && c.con.offering_group__c!='Workstation 10 Support/Subscription','background-color:#C0E2E2','background-color:#D4D4D4')}" headervalue="{!$Label.IUL_Type}">
                {!if(!c.con.IsSnS__c && c.con.offering_group__c!='Fusion 6 Support/Subscription' && c.con.offering_group__c!='Workstation 10 Support/Subscription','Product','SNS')}
                </apex:column>


                                                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}" styleClass="check{!c.counter}" rendered="{!if(c.con.IsSnS__c,false,true)}" />
```

How to write below 2 condition in Lightning Component.

- `<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"
  styleClass="check{!c.counter}"
  rendered="{!if(c.con.IsSnS__c,false,true)}" />`
- `{!if(!c.con.IsSnS__c && c.con.offering_group__c!='Fusion 6 Support/Subscription' && c.con.offering_group__c!='Workstation 10 Support/Subscription','Product','SNS')}`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for conditional styling in Lightning Component. A sample example would be:-

This expression uses the ternary operator to conditionally output one of two values dependent on a condition.

```
<a class="{!v.location == '/active' ? 'selected' : ''}" href="#/active">Active</a>
```

The {!v.location == '/active' ? 'selected' : ''} expression conditionally sets the class attribute of an HTML  tag, by checking whether the location attribute is set to /active. If true, the expression sets class to selected.

Some of the resources that would help you on this are:-

1. [Conditional coloring on a lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169671/conditional-coloring-on-a-lightning-component)
2. [Adding and Removing Styles in Lightning Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm)
3. [Conditional Expressions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_conditional.htm)
4. [Setting Dynamic style classes for Aura components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173633/setting-dynamic-style-classes-for-aura-components/173649)